# Line contains IF problems

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
 For Each removeword In RichTextBox1.Lines
     If Not removeword = "" Then

         For Each line In LoadedLines.Lines
             If line.Contains(removeword) Then

                 RichTextBox2.Visible = True
                 LoadedLines.Visible = False

                 RichTextBox2.Text = RichTextBox2.Text + vbNewLine + line
             End If
          Next
     End If
 Next
```

This is the code I have.

I have a `LoadedLines` `RichTextBox` (it contains the strings to be edited).

`RichTextBox1` contains strings, it checks if a line contains one of those strings.

**The Problem:**

If I run it like that, I get all lines containing one of the removewords in `RichTextBox2`.

But, if I run it with:

```
If Not line.Contains(removeword)
```

It does not add the other lines to `RichTextBox2`, it just removes some of the `removeword` lines (very confusing).

Already tried many other methods like storing it in an array then writing in to the `RichTextBox2` but it didn't work.

Overwriting the `LoadedLines` `RichTextBox` doesn't work; e.g. when I did:

```
If line.Contains(removeword) Then
    line = ""
    '(...)
```

Comment: Im sorry for that. I hope you still find a way to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a temporary `List(Of String)` to store the results of the comparison, then verify if a line has already been inserted in the temporary list and add a new line only if it has not been selected before.

Something like this:

```
Dim LinesList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

For Each line As String In LoadedLines.Lines
    If line.Length > 0 Then
        For Each removeword As String In RichTextBox1.Lines
            If (removeword.Length > 0) AndAlso Not (LinesList.Contains(line)) Then
                If line.Contains(removeword) Then
                    LinesList.Add(line)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

If it's interensting, here's a possible `LINQ` substitute:

```
Dim LinesList As List(Of String) =
        RichTextBox1.Lines.Where(Function(RemovedWord) RemovedWord.Length > 0).
                SelectMany(Function(RemovedWord)
                               Return LoadedLines.Lines.
                                   Where(Function(ln) ln.Length > 0 AndAlso 
                                                      ln.Contains(RemovedWord))
                           End Function).ToList()
```

Use a boolean selector to return the List of lines that contain words to remove or the lines that do not contain any, using `LINQ` `Except()` method:

```
Dim ContainsRemovedWords As Boolean = True

If LinesList.Count > 0 Then
    RichTextBox2.Visible = True
    LoadedLines.Visible = False
    If ContainsRemovedWords Then
        RichTextBox2.AppendText(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                                LinesList.Select(Function(ln) ln)))
    Else
        RichTextBox2.AppendText(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                                LoadedLines.Lines.Except(LinesList)))
    End If
End If
```

In case you need to remove empty lines from the `Except()` List, you can  add a `Where()` filter:

```
RichTextBox2.AppendText(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                        LoadedLines.Lines.Except(LinesList2).
                        Where(Function(ln) ln.Length > 0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

So you have a list of words (let's say they're: Able, Baker, Charlie & Dog) contained in richTextBox1

So we know we're always looping 4 times in the inital run

Then we're going to loop through all the loaded lines:

when we find one of these that contains the removeword we add it to another richtextbox.

Now let's look at this the other way with Not Contains

Loop1 (Able)
We add all lines that don't contain able
Loop2 (Baker)
We add all line that don't contain baker (including the one that has Able in it because this iteration is looking for Baker)
Loop3 (Charlie)
continues this process.

So by using Not, and because you are not removing any lines from LoadedLines,  you're adding every line multiple time. The only time you're not is if the current iteration contains the removeword.

Comment: I LOVE YOU FOR TELLING <3 CAN YOU PROVIDE ME AN CODE EXAMPLE BRO

Comment: A code example of what? I just explained why your code was not working as you intended it to. The logic of adding lines that contain none of the remove words is part of the programming experience. Break the problem down into smaller chunks. You need to either remove lines or somehow only add the current line if you find none of the removewords in it. Make an attempt to code this and then come back when you're stuck with an example of what you have for help.